# How to set up SVN repository in xCode 9.0

Tags: svn, version-control, xcode9

With xCode 9.0, I am facing problem with SVN setup.

I could not find any option to add SVN repository which was working
 proper with earlier versions of xCode.

In source control, I am getting GIT everywhere. I am using SVN for
 long time and was properly working with earlier versions of xCode but
 this is not working with xCode 9.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am adding this answer as I found **work around** for this (Not as a full fledge solution)

If you have upgraded your xCode version to 9.0, and could not find anything to attach your code to SVN repository then following steps will help you out:

1. Take latest checkout from Terminal
2. Open you code in xCode8 (> 8.0 and < 9.0)
3. GO to Source Control
4. You may get an alert to upgrade subversion to 1.9
5. Click on upgrade
6. Now open same code in xCode9.0, you are now ready for all svn commits and updates.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have older version of xcode and above method of upgrade is not working or cannot be used then Terminal can be used to upgrade.

1. Go to Terminal
2. change directory to the project folder base, using cd  command
3. To verify if you are at the base run the command "ls -l". You should see a folder named .svn
4. run the command "svn upgrade"
5. If you see Upgraded message then all done OK. Restart Xcode to see the SVN commands under Source Control menu.

Answer (score 2):

I could checkout a SVN repository from Xcode 9.2

I went to source control->clone->choose option svn and authentication and checkout.

Comment: Hi, I'm using Xcode 9.4.1 and can't seem to see this option. Is SVN removed on this version?

Answer (score 1):

All mentions of subversion seem to be gone from XCode 9, but it still works, and it's actually terribly simple:

(tested with XCode 9.4.1)

1. Go to Source Control->Clone...

[image: Source Control -> Clone]

2. You've probably seen this screen and stopped, because it says GitHub prominently. BUT, notice the "Enter repository URL" text bar at the top! You can just write your subversion URL there and hit Clone!

[image: Add Github Account (!?) Screen]

3. Like so. As you hit the Clone button, you'll be asked to enter your svn credentials (if needed), and the directory where the repo will be cloned.

[image: Entering svn repo]

4. After that, just open your project or workspace from the cloned dir, and you're all set. Even the new Source Control Navigator (command+2), should work right away.

[image]

I haven't figured out how to add things to a subversion repo, but for existing repos, this works. I've not tried this on XCode 10 beta at this time, either.

Comment: I have done that what you told here, but there is no file copied on repository ? how to do that ?

Comment: What happens after you hit the clone button? Mine asks for credentials, clone location and then just starts copying the files.

Comment: mine ask for same things but does not copy anything in that directory :(

Comment: This process copies everything to the mac, which I don't want.  I want to save my work to a Subversion server.  Why is this hard?