# Add Repository option is missing in Xcode 9.2 in Accounts tab in Xcode Preferences

Tags: xcode, projects-and-solutions, xcode9.2

I am trying to add my project in svn, previously in Accounts tab of Xcode Preferences, add respository option will be there but now i am unable to find it, instead there are someother git options is there, i checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46357688/how-to-set-up-svn-repository-in-xcode-9-0) but its not working.

Now i got strucked to add my project in svn, please help me.

Comment: I second that.  I'd like to add SVN to XCode too but the option isn't there.  My only options under Xcode, preferences, accounts, add, are Apple ID, GitHub, GitHub Enterprise and Xcode server

Comment: Yes, these are the options available now, I am unable find any link to explain how to add the project in svn in xcode 9