# How to use SVN source control in Xcode 9.x?

Tags: svn, xcode9.3

I want to use SVN for my source control. SVN is running on one of our local server and working well with other projects/IDE. In Xcode Version 9.3 I can't find any way to share my project into SVN.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set up SVN repository in xCode 9.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46357688/how-to-set-up-svn-repository-in-xcode-9-0)

Comment: Have you find any solution to this? Im having the same issue right now

Comment: There is a workaround in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/46357787/2206209 but I didn't try it. I am using a SVN tool.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51563522/2344535). In summary:

1. Go to Source Control->Clone...
2. Enter your subversion URL in the text box at the top of the window
3. Hit the Clone button
4. Enter svn credentials and choose local copy dir
5. Open your project/workspace from the newly cloned dir